# NuGet include arbitrary file in project root

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuspec

I have the following files (simplified for this example):

- Library.dll
- Data.xml

I want to create a nuspec (NuGet) file to where the Library.dll will be added as a reference and Data.xml will be copied to the root of the project that is referencing the nuget.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
...
...
...
        <references>
            <reference file="Library.dll" />
        </references>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="lib\netcoreapp2.1\Library.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp2.1\Emgu.CV.World.NetStandard1_4.dll" />
        <file src="..\..\Data.xml" target="Data.xml" />
    </files>
</package>
```

**Problem**

The library is referenced however Data.xml is not copied over, what can I do to get the Data.xml file to copied over to the root of the project referencing the NuGet ?

**NOTE**: After the NuGet is generated, I'm adding the NuGet through Visual Studio 2017 normal "Manage NuGet Packages" option

Comment: The content you have appears to be correct from a quick scan, are you sure that your relative pathing is correct? From the directory that NuGet is running the pack, is the Data file back two directories?

Comment: Yes I'm sure the relative path is correct.  In fact when the path is wrong generating the nupkg file from the nuspec file will error out. But in my case it generates the nupkg fine.

Comment: You're outputting that Data.xml file at the root of the package you're creating; are you sure it's not there? I just created a quick sample nuspec with the same setup and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Oh, I think maybe I'm misunderstanding your issue. It seems likely to me (based on my own tests) that the file is indeed part of the actual .nupkg (if you rename to .zip you can peek inside), but you're hoping to see it extract into the project referencing the package, is that correct?

Comment: Right, so my goal is that the Data.xml file will be in the root of the published project, I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: A couple more questions then, why do you want to put it in the root of the project? Are you hoping the user will edit it? Is it a config file of sorts? Otherwise, you might want to look at specifying the "content type" so that the file isn't ever actually in the project, but will still end up in the output when built. [These docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files) are what I'm referencing, if that helps.

Comment: I've looked through many guides but can't seem to figure it out. Well, basically when I publish the project (that is referencing the NuGet package) it gets published to say /publish/<project files here>, in the publish directory I have the project and it's dependencies and since Data.xml is a dependency I need it there to access it.  User access is handled differently, basically just think of Data.xml as content that needs to get published as well but needs to be part of the NuGet package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188642/discussion-between-shortstuffsushi-and-exocomp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped is going through this article: https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html

It will do a better job then me trying to explain it so get some coffee and have at it.